# Minimum number of points such that each line segment contains a point

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl

I'm tackling with a problem where I have to find the minimum number as well as the points such that all the given line segments would have atleast one point in their span.

Input is of the format - number of line segments followed by start,finish of each.

Output required is of the form - number of points along with its value

**My approach**: I am sorting the line segments in ascending order of finish values, iterating over them, adding them to the output list:  and then comparing line segment start points with that end point. If the given start point is <=, we remove that `start,end` pair.

My code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

struct Segment {
  int start, end;
};

struct less_than_key
{
    inline bool operator() (const Segment& struct1, const Segment& struct2)
    {
        return (struct1.end < struct2.end);
    }
};

vector<int> optimal_points(vector<Segment> &segments) {
  vector<int> points;
  sort(segments.begin(),segments.end(),less_than_key());
  vector<Segment> ss = segments;
  vector<int> output;
  int p=0;
  int t=0;
  while(segments.size()!=0)
  {
    int m = segments[p].end;
    int q=0;
    output.push_back(m);
    while(t==0)
    {
        if(q>=segments.size())
        {
            t=t+1;
            continue;
        }
        if(segments[q].start<=m)
        {                                                                                      
            segments.erase(segments.begin()+q);
            q=q-1;
        }
        q=q+1;
    }
  }
  return output;
}

int main() {
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  vector<Segment> segments(n);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < segments.size(); ++i) {
    std::cin >> segments[i].start >> segments[i].end;
  }
  vector<int> points = optimal_points(segments);
  std::cout << points.size() << "\n";
  for (size_t i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << points[i] << " ";
  }
}
```

This code is working for very particular inputs and resulting in infinite loops in some. The logic should work perfectly on paper but my code is bugging out somewhere.

Running data -

```
Input - 
3 
1 3 
2 5 
3 6

Output - 
1
3
```

Works correctly as the point 3 will result in each segment having a point.

Comment: *The logic should work perfectly on paper but my code is bugging out somewhere.* -- There is a tool that all programmers should know how to use, and that is the *debugger*.  Have you used the debugger to single-step through your code, to see where the program flow diverges from your planned logic?

Comment: The code runs into an infinite loop in some cases and works well for some which is the main reason why I'm at a standstill

Comment: Where is the test data?

Comment: Changed the question

Comment: Please post the data that fails.  You could also make the code easier to understand if you used meaningful variable names, not single-letter names like `m`, `q`, etc.

Comment: Also, if you read what you wrote in the question, that entire `while` loop is `std::remove_if`.  This is how you ensure that what you write down on paper matches the code you actually write, and that is to use, as much as possible, the STL algorithm functions.  By looking at your code using `m`, `p`, `q`, `t`, etc., I don't know if what you have there matches what you think you're actually doing.

Comment: Your program enters an infinite loop whenever you have disjoint segments requiring more than one point, e.g. `[1,2], [3,4]`. The first time you finish scanning all segments (by `q`) you set `t == 1`. From that point on, `while(t==0)` loop never runs, nothing is erased from `segments`, and the program doesn't make any progress.